# Write text to the next line using Java

Tags: java

So i'm trying to write stuff to a file and it works but when i call this method more than once it removes the previous stuff i wrote with the new. So i wonder what should i do so the method wont remove my previous text that i've added to the file and adds the new text to the
 next line.

```
public static void writetofile(String id, String content) throws IOException
{
    try {

        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter("Random.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
        out.write(id+" "+ content);
        out.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the javadoc of `FileWriter`.

Comment: You need to tell FileWriter to append to the existing file, rather than over-writing.

Comment: @user3320160: Please reward the people who have helped you and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) of your questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter("Random.txt", true);
```

As per java doc

Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is `true`, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

```
Parameters:
```

file - a File object to write to

append - if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning

Answer (score 2):

There is constructor signature of `FileWriter` with a boolean parameter which controls append behavior. Providing that appending is what you want, you should construct the `FileWriter` with this boolean set to `true`:

```
FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter("Random.txt", true);
```

Note, that in case of single parameter constructor the output is written to the beginning of the file (see the implementation of `FileOutputStream` which is wrapped by `FileWriter`), so calling single parameter constructor is equivalent to setting the boolean parameter to `false`.